# Laravel5.3 Eloquent Relationships not gettiing exact record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel5.3 Eloquent Relationships for fetching records from three table.

**Client Table:**

[image: Client Table]

**Service Table:**
[image]

**Subscribe_services Table:**

[image]

I want to display client listing with subscribed services but I'm not getting service name I'm only getting data from subscribe_service table

**Client Model:**

```
    class Client extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $table = "clients";
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','country','place','mobile_no','email', 'password','api_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

        public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubscribeService');
    }
```

**Client Blade:**

```
 <select>
                    @foreach($user->services as $services)
                    <option>{{$services->service_id}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
```

How can i get service name ?Please any suggestion

Comment: If you're using a pivot table, it usually means that the relationship between models (`Client` and `Service`) is a `manyToMany`, so the relationship between each in Laravel should be `belongsToMany` and not `hasMany`. Check the documentation for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `hasMany()` here, do this:

```
$client = Client::with('services.service')->find($id);

@foreach ($client->services as $service)
    {{ $service->service->name }}
@endforeach
```

To make this work, you should add this relationship to the `SubscribeService` model:

```
public function service()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');
}
```

Alternatively, you can use many-to-many relationship by defining `belongsToMany()` relationships. In this case, you could do this:

```
$client = Client::with('services')->find($id);

@foreach ($client->services as $service)
    {{ $service->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey,

I' m  using last one but its return same record im not getting  service object in the record.

 [{"id":1,"client_id":7,"service_id":1,"created_at":"2017-03-25 11:27:04","updated_at":"2017-03-25 00:00:00"},{"id":2,"client_id":7,"service_id":2,"created_at":"2017-03-25 11:27:04","updated_at":"2017-03-25 00:00:00"},{"id":3,"client_id":7,"service_id":3,"created_at":"2017-03-25 11:27:04","updated_at":"2017-03-25 00:00:00"},{"id":4,"client_id":7,"service_id":4,"created_at":"2017-03-25 11:27:04","updated_at":"2017-03-25 00:00:00"}]

Comment: Added relationship in SubscribeService Model:

public function service()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');
}

and in client model :

      public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubscribeService');
    }

Comment: I'm getting the correct  response but not able to use service object:
{"id":7,"name":"Jhon Walker","email":"jhon.walker@gmail.com","mobile_no":"788898","country":"singapur","place":"indore","api_token":"$Xc7ohG","created_at":"2017","updated_at":"2017","services":[{"id":1,"client_id":7,"service_id":1,"created_at":"2017 11:27:04","updated_at":"2017-03-25 00:00:00","service":{"id":1,"title":"Investor Delight","description":"This product is designed for Investor who believes in buy & hold approachstocks.","publish":0,"free_trial":"","created_at":"2017-03-23 18:10:53","updated_at":null}]}

Comment: @aniruddh you said you're using the second way. But in my answer, I wrote that if you want to use `hasMany()` you should use the first option. If you want to use the second option, you should define `belongsToMany()` relationship.